# How to set media queries for high resolution screens in html

Tags: css, media-queries, retina-display

I have a query. How to set media queries for high-resolution screens like 4k, 5k, retina display etc. As I have been reading about it, I understood we can use resolution specific media queries. But I have a query of how to understand the breakpoints for 4k 5k screens and how to know they reliability towards future high-resolution screens. 
Can anyone suggest how to use CSS for high res screens?

Comment: Grammatical mistakes corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you will use relative units (**em**, or **rem**) it will give you a possibility to equal scaling for elements, and to write a minimum media queries.

**EDITED:**

You can see how to use **em** on this example:

```css
.parent {
  background: red;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.child {
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.childOfChild {
  margin-left: 1em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h2 class="child">
    Hello World!
    <span class="childOfChild">Some Text</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

You can see how to use **rem** on this example:

```css
html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.child {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

.childOfChild {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  margin-left: 1.2rem;
}

@media (min-width: 2000px) {
  html {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  html {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h2 class="child">
    Hello World!
    <span class="childOfChild">Some Text</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

Comment: can you please futher elaborate it.. does that mean giving media queries in rem/em ?

Comment: Em/rem is relative values. For example if you use em, you need to give to a parent element font-size property, (font-size: 20px), and it’s mean that 1em = 20px for all childs. But if you define for some child font-size again, then all his child will have a value relative to it. If you use rem - it means that you want to have size relative to root element(html). You need to set only size for html tag, for example font-size: 14px, and it means that 1rem = 14px

Comment: On some media-queries , you can redefine it values, and they will be proportional changed everywhere.

Comment: Thank you Andrew for your answer, but what Iwas looking for is media queries to use.. em/ rem values are something I am well versed with now

Comment: @Shruti i think media-query don't have that options, but relative values give us a possibility to scale proportional

Comment: yes that was my thought to work on ems/rems rather to use stack of media queries.. but I got confused with bootstraps big grid media queries and zurb foundation's media queires in em/rem